# Cannot link external files to a php

Tags: php, html, css

I am writing a php file and I tried to link a css file to it. But I found that I could not link an external file to the php. I tried to put the content of the css file inside the php and it works but failed at the codes where I want to link an external picture. I am running the php on the server of my school. Does anyone know what should I do? Thank you.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">; <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml"; lang = "en-us"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<title>Login to the administrator page</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/default.css" />
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you used.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang = "en-us">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Login to the administrator page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/default.css" />

Comment: it is more html question than php, check http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: @user1200781 You should try inserting the FULL URL to the css file. Eg: **http: //www.mysite.com/css/default.css**

Answer (score 3):

Your `href` is probably wrong, unless you're storing your CSS in the root of your server.  Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
```

Comment: Do you think that it is possible that the server stops me from linking an external file?

Comment: I doubt that.  If you could provide more information about your situation in your question, we could help you more.

Comment: @user1200781 use firebug or chrome dev console to get the error about your css, it is 404 or other code ?

Comment: I tried to load the resource in chrome console. I got a error code 403.

Comment: then `css/default.css` doesn't exist.  Check your file structure.

Answer (score 1):

If your folder structure is like this:

- index.html
- css/default.css
- images/logo.png
- images/bg.jpg

Then you could include the css file using: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />`

And inside the CSS, for the URL of images, you could use it like this: `../images/bg.jpg`

Example:

```
.sampleclass
{
  background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
}
```

Comment: yes, I did that. But I don't know why nothing happened. Seems all links of external files don't work.

Comment: can you please provide more details regarding the external file? Where is the file located in the server? Is it just CSS ?